# Java instance control

Tags: java

Does Java recognize instances across overloaded versions of static factory methods?

For example, for the code -

```
 static IPlatform  registerElseGet(Long PlatformId)
 static IPlatform  registerElseGet(String PlatformName)
```

If a client runs -

```
IPlatform pName = registerElseGet("MySQL"); // say the service creates MySQL and assigns id 1
IPlatform pId = registerElseGet(1);
```

Will pName == pId?

If not, is there a way to achieve this - so I don't create duplicate instances?

Comment: From what you've shown: I don't know.  From what you're presuming:  it wouldn't be immediately obvious that they're the same instance, considering that they're called with different arguments (so one would believe that they're different instances).

Comment: This is a simple syntax question that you could just try.  If I understand correctly, yes, you can overload static methods like you show without problems.

Comment: That depends entirely on how these static factory methods are implemented. Static factory methods are not a language feature of Java, so the language has nothing to say about them.

Comment: OK, if you're asking about the return values: yes it depends 100% on the implementation.  Please show us some code so we can comment on it.

Comment: Might be irrelevant to question directly, but this would be a side effect. Try calling `registerElseGet(null);` It will throw exception, you need to be aware of that.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - Thanks!



`public static IPlatform buildElseGet(String platformName){

 IPlatformProvider iPlatformProvider = providers.get(platformName.toLowerCase());

 if (iPlatformProvider == null){
   iPlatformProvider = new PlatformProvider();

   providers.put(platformName.toLowerCase(), iPlatformProvider);

 }

    return iPlatformProvider.newPlatform(platformName);
  }
`

Comment: Anybody?? @SebastianRedl??

Comment: It looks like you're using some 3rd party library that we don't know. Also, a comment is a very bad place for code; you should edit your post instead.